# No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

> D:\new openvpn\OpenVPN\qca\botantools\botan\botan\allocate.h:37: error: botan/botan/types.h: No such file or directory

Кто знает что за ошибка и как исправить?

Answer (score 2):

В файле `D:\new openvpn\OpenVPN\qca\botantools\botan\botan\allocate.h` в строчке 37 подключают файл botan/botan/types.h директивой #include но компилятор не может найти данный файл.

А исправить этот баг, нужно найти этот файл и положить в нужное место.

Answer (score 1):

А лучше использовать относительные пути к файлам, например если приложение лежит в папке `D:\new openvpn\OpenVPN`

```
#include <.\\qca\\botantools\\botan\\botan\\allocate.h>
```